# ActiveRecord to_i method removed in Rails 3.2.9

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

Upgraded to Rails 3.2.9 today from 3.2.7 and it appears that the method "to_i" has been removed from ActiveRecord.

Is this by design?  Or is it a bug?  I cannot find any mention of it in the change notes.  This is going to impact a lot of code.

thanks!

Comment: I'm on 3.2.6 and there's no `to_i` on activerecord objects or relations ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `#to_i` method never existed, however the way assigning objects to values has [changed in Rails 3.2.8](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/96a13fc7).

Given the following:

```
class Lecture < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :professor
end
```

Previously you could assign a professor to a lecture like this:

```
@lecture.professor = Professor.find_by_id(1)
```

Or like this:

```
@lecture.professor_id = Professor.find_by_id(1)
```

In the first case everything is simple as the `professor` association expects a professor object. In the second case though ActiveRecord performed some magic to coerce the id from the professor, as `professor_id` expects a integer instead.

In Rails 3.2.8 and above that magic no longer works. It is nice in a way as it is a hint you are probably doing something wrong. For example, if there isn't a `professor_id` column in the database, but just `professor` which expects an integer, assigning like this will no longer work.

It looks like this will be [reverted to the previous behaviour in Rails 3.2.11](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/e842dbbdf74c1aec904a6325f1e5d84924b90e94).

Comment: There was no "magic to coerce the id from the professor" in 3.2.8 and below - it always assigned 1, not the object id.

Answer (score 2):

There has been one change with regards to "to_i" method in Rails 3.2.9, but that deals with the columns and not with the tables.
See [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/7509).

So in your code, if you were passing entire object instead of column value, it was failing silently before. But now it will actually call the "to_i" method on the object and raise exception.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same error.  It's not that ActiveRecord lacks #to_i but something else, which in my case involves the factory_girl gem.

```
factory_girl (4.1.0)
factory_girl_rails (4.1.0)
```

Here's an isolated case of the difference:

```
rails _3.1.0_ new rails31
cd rails31
bundle install
rails g scaffold note title:string contents:text
rails g scaffold user name:string
rails g migration add_user_id_to_notes user_id:integer
rake db:migrate
```

Then in the console:

```
require 'factory_girl'
FactoryGirl.define { factory :note }
Factory(:note, :user_id => User.first, :title => 'foo')
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "notes" ("contents", "created_at", "title", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["contents", nil], ["created_at", Sun, 13 Jan 2013 21:29:36 UTC +00:00], ["title", "foo"], ["updated_at", Sun, 13 Jan 2013 21:29:36 UTC +00:00], ["user_id", 1]]
 => #<Note id: 3, title: "foo", contents: nil, created_at: "2013-01-13 21:29:36", updated_at: "2013-01-13 21:29:36", user_id: 1>
```

However, if I do the same sequence of steps with:

```
rails _3.2.11_ new rails3211
```

Then in the console I see:

```
1.9.2-p290 :001 > require 'factory_girl'
 => true 
1.9.2-p290 :002 > FactoryGirl.define { factory :note }
 => [] 
1.9.2-p290 :003 > Factory(:note, :user_id => User.first, :title => 'foo')
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" LIMIT 1
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (24.5ms)  INSERT INTO "notes" ("contents", "created_at", "title", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["contents", nil], ["created_at", Sun, 13 Jan 2013 21:33:03 UTC +00:00], ["title", "foo"], ["updated_at", Sun, 13 Jan 2013 21:33:03 UTC +00:00], ["user_id", nil]]
   (2.4ms)  commit transaction
 => #<Note id: 1, title: "foo", contents: nil, created_at: "2013-01-13 21:33:03", updated_at: "2013-01-13 21:33:03", user_id: nil>
```

Note the nil user_id for Rails 3.2.11

Comment: I guess now if column is id, we need to supply an id: `:user_id => User.first.id`

Comment: This is correct - 3.2.9 onwards now raises an exception if you try to assign an ActiveRecord object to an integer column. Before 3.2.8 this was actually broken - `Factory(:note, :user_id => User.find(6))` would actually have still set `user_id` to 1, not 6 as you might expect from the ID. You should always call `User.first.id`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that the `to_i` method has event been available on the AR objects them selves. Can you be a little more specific about the earlier uses of the method, that now fails?

Answer (score 0):

To follow up on Luca, I'm using Rails 3.2.11 and I'm not sure I have such code, but I did find this to no longer work:

```
@lecture.update_attribute(:professor_id, Professor.find_by_id(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah me too got the same issue when i upgrade rails version 3.2.3 into rails 3.2.11.

Here is some code snippets what exact issue is there

In rails 3.2.3
doctor = Doctor.first
patient = Patient.new
patient.doctor_id =doctor (Right side Object assignment is valid)
patient.save! (valid)

In rails 3.2.11
doctor = Doctor.first
patient = Patient.new
patient.doctor_id = doctor (Right side Object assignment is invalid)
patient.save! (invalid)
NoMethodError: undefined method 'to_i' error we got this kind of assignments.

CONCLUSION IS WE MUSE USE _ID = INTEGER ONLY not just like object assignments.
 [More details](http://madhan-tech-updates.blogspot.in/2013/01/undefined-method-toi-in-rails-3211.html)